# Different results in SOQL while fetching records

Tags: php, salesforce, soql

I have attachment table in Salesforce. When I am using "Select Id from Attachment", it return all the records. But when I am using "Select Id,Body from Attachment", it only return on record.

Please note: Body returns Base64

Comment: Please provide more detail and the code that may be failing. We have almost nothing to work with here. I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

When you query a blob field, like Body on attachment, the results are returned one row at a time, you need to call queryMore (soap api) or use the nextRecords url (rest API) to fetch the remaining rows in the query result.